# "Cannot resolve dependency" when importing local dependency in monorepo - Parcel, Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, parcel, monorepo

I am trying to set up a monorepo with parcel and typescript. I have four packages: f-app, f-app-core, f-app-hub, f-app-notes.

when I try to import from one package to another, I get `Cannot resolve dependency`

For example: I want to import f-app-hub/index.tsx in f-app/index.tsx.

```
// f-app/index.tsx

import React from 'react'

import Hub from 'f-app-hub' // this fails

const App = () => {
  return <Hub />
}
```

I get `Cannot resolve dependency 'f-app-hub'` during build.
However, VS Code shows no errors and is able to correctly identify and source f-app-hub. cmd+space sends me to the correct file.

Importing f-app-hub as a relative path also works.

```
// f-app/index.tsx

import React from 'react'

import Hub from '../f-app-hub' // this works

const App = () => {
  return <Hub />
}
```

Here is ny tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "packages",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["packages/*"]
    },
  },
  "include": ["packages/**/*"]
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Only If `f-app-hub` were a node_module(library) like react, `import Hub from 'f-app-hub'` fails as `f-app-hub` is a file so you need to explicitly define the path for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using the parcel alias field in package.json

```
"alias": {
  "f-app-core": "./packages/f-app-core"
  "f-app-hub": "./packages/f-app-hub",
  "f-app-notes": "./packages/f-app-notes"
}
```

Comment: HI. Glad you solved this. How do you fix this for npm modules? For example see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69479427/cannot-resolve-dependency-react-side-effect-using-pnpm-and-parcel